# Ajax asynchronicity calls end function before inner loop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chart.js

This is the code i am struggling with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSets = [];
    getSensorIDs().done(function (result) {
        var sensorIDs = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        $.each(sensorIDs, function (index, value) { //loop through each id
            getDataBySensorID(value.id).done(function (res) {
                var temperatureData = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                var dataPoints = [];
                $.each(temperatureData, function (index, value) {
                    dataPoints.push({
                        x: index
                        , y: value.value
                    });
                })
                dataSets.push(buildDataset(dataPoints, 1));
                alert("Pushed something.");
            });
        });
        alert("Drawed something.");
        drawChart(dataSets);
    })
});
```

The problem is: `Drawed something` happens ahead of `Pushed something` even though the program flow doesn't like look it would. I thought i fixed the `problem` of ajax (it's asynchron) with `.done()` but it doesn't seem like that. What would be a proper fix for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is working exactly as it should because the "pushed something" code is in a **NESTED** AJAX request's `done` callback. That will be sometime in the future. And so, the JavaScript engine continues on processing the rest of the code, which includes "Drawed something" in the top-level AJAX request next, so that happens.

At some point in the future, the AJAX call will complete and the `done` callback will fire and then you will get "pushed something".

```
// 1. When the document is ready...
$(document).ready(function () {
    var dataSets = [];

    // 2. Make the AJAX call, BUT DONE RUN .done YET!
    getSensorIDs().done(function (result) {

        var sensorIDs = jQuery.parseJSON(result);

        // loop through each id
        $.each(sensorIDs, function (index, value) { 

            // 3. As part of the first AJAX call, make a SECOND one
            getDataBySensorID(value.id).done(function (res) {
                var temperatureData = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
                var dataPoints = [];
                $.each(temperatureData, function (index, value) {
                    dataPoints.push({
                        x: index
                        , y: value.value
                    });
                }); 

                // 5. The nested call finishes last
                dataSets.push(buildDataset(dataPoints, 1));
                alert("Pushed something.");

            });  

        });

        // 4. This runs first because the first AJAX call is finishing 
        // before the nested one (above)
        alert("Drawed something.");
        drawChart(dataSets);

    });  

});
```

Comment: How can i rewrite my code so that i first create the datasets in the nested code block and then call `drawChart` because currently `dataSets` is empty.

Comment: I would move `alert("Drawed something."); drawChart(dataSets);` to be just before your `$.each` loop.

Comment: You have to call `drawChart` in the last asynchronous callback. Promises will help with this, you can use `Promise.all()` to wait for all the promises to complete.